# Hiding WooCommerce Categories that don't have any products in them?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to disable categories that don't have any products in them. Here's the code that seems to not be working.

Placed in my functions.php

```
 function woo_hide_product_categories_widget( $list_args ){
$list_args[ 'hide_empty' ] = 1;

return $list_args;
 }
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args','woo_hide_product_categories_widget' );
```

Answer (score 0):

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'wpsites_exclude_product_cat_widget' );

function wpsites_exclude_product_cat_widget( $args ) {

$args['exclude'] = array('16','46');

return $args;
}

try this

Comment: what the problem now ?

Comment: It's not hiding the unused category.

Comment: get your category by id and pass into array simply

Answer (score 0):

you can hide specific categories by the following:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'uw_remove_product_cats_shop_page' );
function uw_remove_product_cats_shop_page( $query ) {

    // Comment out the line below to hide products in the admin as well
    if ( is_admin() ) return;

    if ( is_shop() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'ID',
                'terms' => array( 200, 205, 210 ), //ID of categories here
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        ) );

    }

}
```